# null pointer exception in string array with assigning null during initialization

Tags: java, string

I am beginner in java.Now i'm facing problem during pratice.Actually i want to get String tokens from a StringTokenizer class and wanna assign these tokens to the array of string.but i'm getting null pointer exception.My code is here.

```
public class Token {
    public static void main(String str[])
    {
        String str1="This is my first page";
        StringTokenizer str2=new StringTokenizer(str1);
        int i=0;
        String d[]=null;
        while(str2.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            d[i]=str2.nextToken();

        }
    System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: `String d[]=null;` Why do you do that? (Then, when you write `d[i].something` it's like writin `null.something` which causes NPE).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays in Java must be initialized. This:

```
String d[] = null;
```

essentially creates a reference to an array, which is null. Hence the `NullPointerException`.

What is more, even if it were initialized, the size is *fixed* and the array *cannot be resized*. You cannot do:

```
String[] d = new String[]; // won't compile: size not specified
```

Continuing on, you do:

```
d[i] = "whatever";
```

and `i` is always 0.

Use a `List<String>` instead:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

and `.add(theString)` to it:

```
while (str2.hasMoreTokens())
    list.add(str2.nextToken());
```

Last but not least, this:

```
System.out.println(d);
```

will not do what you think it does. It will print the string representation of the *array reference*. If you want a string representation of the array plus its elements, do:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(d));
```

Answer (score 4):

You should count the token and initialize the string array based on that using `str2.countTokens()`

And printing should be done inside the loop..

```
public static void main(String str[]) {
    String str1 = "This is my first page";
    StringTokenizer str2 = new StringTokenizer(str1);
    int i = 0;
    String d[] = new String[str2.countTokens()];
    while (str2.hasMoreTokens()) {
        d[i] = str2.nextToken();
        System.out.println(d[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to populate a `null`array is unacceptable:

```
String d[]=null;
```

Change it to `String[] d = new String[20];`, but here is another problem, you don't know how many tokens you will get, so using a dynamic list (e.g. `ArrayList`) will be finer.

Comment: Sir i think we can assign null to a reference variable then we can assign value to it..

Comment: @TusharPaliwal if you assign null to array, there will be no space allocated for the array in the memory. so how can you assign values to the entries of an unallocated array? you simply cannot.

Comment: Not with arrays, you can't

Answer (score 1):

Better use a List in you case because u don't know how many Elements the tokenizer returns.

```
public static void main(String str[])
{
    String str1="This is my first page";
    StringTokenizer str2=new StringTokenizer(str1);
    int i=0;
    List<String> d=new ArrayList<String>();
    while(str2.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        d.add(str2.nextToken());

    }
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use token count for array initialization:

```
String d[]=new String[str2.countTokens()];
```

Answer (score 1):

StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

The following example illustrates how the String.split method can be used to break up a string into its basic tokens:

```
     String[] result = "this is a test".split("\\s");
     for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++)
         System.out.println(result[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You define `d[]` as `null`, and then access element `i`. That is causing the `NullPointerException`.

What you should do is initialize `d[]` big enough for all your tokens to fit, for example `String d[] = new String[100]`.

Oh, and don't forget to increment your counter `i`.

Instead of using an array, consider using a `List<String>`, as it will dynamically increase so you won't have to pick an initial size that is big enough for all your data to fit in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for 
[Array initialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @HinataHyuga Thanks for your recommendation. I will do this for my following answers.